# When overflow, what does move %rbx, %rsi do?

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86-64

This is the assembly code of my function.
This is run with gcc -O2 -fsanitize=undefined

```
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   53                      push   %rbx
   2:   48 ba ff ff ff ff ff    movabs $0x7fffffffffffffff,%rdx
   9:   ff ff 7f
   c:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  10:   48 8b 1d 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0(%rip),%rbx        # 17 <testovf+0x17>
  17:   48 89 dd                mov    %rbx,%rbp
  1a:   48 01 d5                add    %rdx,%rbp
  1d:   70 0d                   jo     2c <testovf+0x2c>
  1f:   48 39 eb                cmp    %rbp,%rbx
  22:   0f 9f c0                setg   %al
  25:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  29:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  2a:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  2b:   c3                      retq
  2c:   48 89 de                mov    %rbx,%rsi
  2f:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
  34:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  39 <testovf+0x39>
  39:   eb e4                   jmp    1f <testovf+0x1f>
```

I understand that when overflow happens in 1a addition, it jumps to 2c.
however, after 2c what does mov    %rbx,%rsi and mov    $0x0,%edi do?
Do they need to be there?

Comment: Tony, stop editting out the body of the question.  Without the code, it's a an incomplete and useless question that should be deleted.  If you have an edit to make, put in the new content at the same time.  If you have a different question, post a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At address `34` you have a `callq` to an external function. The two instructions you ask about set up the arguments for that function, which according to standard 64 bit calling convention are passed in registers `rdi` and `rsi`.

Note that the target of the call is shown as `39 <testovf+0x39>` but that's not correct. Chances are, you got this listing from objdump and forgot to use the `-r` option which would show you relocation entries.

Comment: When I use -r option only things added to the code are:
                        30: R_X86_64_32 .data+0x20
  34:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  39 <testovf+0x39>
                        35: R_X86_64_PC32       __ubsan_handle_add_overflow-0x4
  39:   eb e4                   jmp    1f <testovf+0x1f>
Do you konw what it means?

Comment: Yes, it shows you the function called is really `__ubsan_handle_add_overflow`.